# How should you specify the verb + resource for method level throttling for API Gateway usage plans via CLI or SDK?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

The [SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/model/ApiStage.html#setThrottle-java.util.Map-) indicates you can specify a map of String to ThrottleSettings for method level throttling, but doesn't indicate the format of the key which contains both a resource path and a verb. How should this String be formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string should include the resource path ending with a slash and then the verb. E.g.: `/pet/{petId}/uploadImage/POST`